# append child node to XML node jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've got XML like this:

```
<REQUEST> 
  <GET_IMAGE> 
   <PROPERTIES>
     <LAYERLIST>
     </LAYERLIST> 
    </PROPERTIES>
   </GET_IMAGE>
</REQUEST>
```

and I wanna to add to node LAYERLIST few other child nodes like this:

```
<LAYER id="1"/>
<LAYER id="2"/>
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to do this by

```
$(xml).find('LAYERLIST').get(0).append(nodes)
```

and when I'm doin just `$(xml).find('LAYERLIST').get(0)` I can get to this node, but when I'm doing `$(xml).find('LAYERLIST').get(0).append(nodes)` I get 'append is not a function'. I tried with appentTo to and effect were pretty much same.

Comment: `.get()` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/get/. Just remove it or use `appendChild` (that of course also depends on what `nodes` is) or use `.eq` instead: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(xml).find('LAYERLIST').eq(0)
```